# Dynamic column selection without a case statement

Tags: arrays, oracle, sum, sign

I have a function I use to give me year-to-date totals.

It takes an accounting period variable (in_period), and twelve amounts.

I take the sign of the difference between the account period + 1 and the lessor of the amount index and the period, multiply that by the amount, and add the resulting products.

Is there a similar method I can use to get just one month?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ytd(in_period IN NUMBER,
                                     bucket_01 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                     bucket_02 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                     bucket_03 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                     bucket_04 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                     bucket_05 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                     bucket_06 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                     bucket_07 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                     bucket_08 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                     bucket_09 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                     bucket_10 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                     bucket_11 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                     bucket_12 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0)
  RETURN NUMBER IS
  RESULT NUMBER;


BEGIN
  the_period := in_period + 1;
  the_sum    := sign(the_period - least(1, the_period)) * bucket_01 +
                sign(the_period - least(2, the_period)) * bucket_02 +
                sign(the_period - least(3, the_period)) * bucket_03 +
                sign(the_period - least(4, the_period)) * bucket_04 +
                sign(the_period - least(5, the_period)) * bucket_05 +
                sign(the_period - least(6, the_period)) * bucket_06 +
                sign(the_period - least(7, the_period)) * bucket_07 +
                sign(the_period - least(8, the_period)) * bucket_08 +
                sign(the_period - least(9, the_period)) * bucket_09 +
                sign(the_period - least(10, the_period)) * bucket_10 +
                sign(the_period - least(11, the_period)) * bucket_11 +
                sign(the_period - least(12, the_period)) * bucket_12;
  RESULT     := the_sum;
  RETURN(RESULT);
END get_ytd;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean get the value of just the one period that is specified, instead of the year to date up through that period?  Why not just this?

```
return decode(in_period,1,bucket_01,2,bucket_02,3,bucket_03, ... etc);
```

### Update for additional restriction of "no case/decode"

```
return (1 - sign(abs(in_period - 1))) * bucket_01 + 
       (1 - sign(abs(in_period - 2))) * bucket_02 +
       (1 - sign(abs(in_period - 3))) * bucket_03 + ...
```

Comment: I like the solution but want to avoid CASE/DECODE statements.

Comment: Why avoid them?  In any case, I've updated my answer to not use them.

Comment: I'm trying to use simple addition/subtraction to "toggle" which buckets are returned.  It's more of a mental exercise than anything.


ABS(in_period - 1) is always going to be positive, so SIGN is superfluous in this case.  


`1 - sign(abs(in_period - 1)` 
evaluates to 1 for an in_period value of 1.  

Extending your example to include bucket two 


`return (2 -sign(abs(in_period - 1))) * bucket_02` will return 2.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  For period #2 it would be `1-sign(abs(in_period-2))` for period #3 it would be `1-sign(abs(in_period-3))` etc.